# How to get a list of unchecked checkboxes when submitting a form?

Tags: php

I have this code for example :

```
$b = "";
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rows)) {
        if ($row['enabled'] == 1) {
                    $b = "checked";
              } else {
                     $b = "":
                     }
```

echo "<\input name='nam[$row[id]]' type='checkbox' value='$row[id]' $b />";

}

When I execute this code, I will get a list of checkboxes, some of them are checked and others are not.

I can use this code to get a list of checked checkboxes.

```
 if (isset($_POST['sub'])) { //check if form has been submitted or not
$nam = $_POST['nam'];
if (!empty($nam)) {

              foreach($nam as $k=>$val){

    // proccess operation with checked checkboxes
               }

}
```

I need to know how I can get list of unckecked checkboxes after submitting the form.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the check boxes are dynamically created this is a trivial task:

Create a naming convention. For example, lets say that each checkbox is tied to a row in the DB, each row in the DB has a primary key. You can name each checkbox based off this key:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foo_1" name="foo_1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="foo_2" name="foo_2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="foo_3" name="foo_3" />
```

Now when the form is submitted you can query the database to get the Id's and process the request as follows:

```
$res = mysql_query("select * from foo;");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    $checked = isset($_POST["foo_{$row['id']}");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers send nothing for unchecked boxes, so your only hope is creating a hidden field that tells you the name of each checkbox (or add a hidden field for each checkbox).

Comment: I don't think create hidden fields is good idea because what if I have 100 rows in my db, I will need a 100 hidden fields!!!

Comment: Then create one hidden field that contains all the checkboxes/ids, separated by commas.

Comment: After I create this hidden field with all checkboxes/ids, separated by commas. How I can know the unchecked ones.

Comment: You split that field in the POST part of your form and subtract the list of checked boxes from the whole list.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I solved a similar problem using JavaScript.

In your form include a function that will be called just before the form get submitted:

```
<form action="" method="get" onsubmit="return submiting()">
```

And in the  section, include:

```
function submiting() {
    elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    for (element of elements) {
        if (element.checked) {
            // Do something, like counting checked boxes.
        }
        else {
            // Do something else, like counting unchecked boxes.
        }
    }
}
```

This question is old, but maybe this helps someone.

Best regards,

Brusque

Comment: The OP is asking about getting unchecked values on server side, not client side.

Comment: Yes @MohammadSalehi. You're right and my answer is incomplete.

The client's side JavaScript function is only part of the solution.

One can create a hidden object on the form where the number of unchecked checkboxes would be stored and sent to the server.

Another solution (that I don't know if it's feasible in the OP's case) is that the server probably knows how many checkboxes it sent to the client. So it would only be a question of subtracting the number of checked checkboxes from the total checkboxes in the form.